# What gonna happen to beer on the moon?

Tags: moon

Let's assume that we have bottle of beer on the Moon. What would happen to it in sunlight?
Some cases:

1. Beer can be dark or lager.
2. It can be contained in glass bottle (transparent or dark) or aluminium can.

Will it freeze or vaporize or what?

Comment: Is the can/bottle open or closed?

Comment: Just curious: why (tasty, tasty) beer and not for example soda, water or wine?

Comment: Oh, you can look at both cases.

I don't know why beer. Maybe because Alan Guth generated some ideas in pub.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to NASA](http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/factsheet/moonfact.html), the temperature on the Moon in direct sunshine can reach 400K and this is above the boiling point of beer. So the beer will boil and possibly burst it's container depending on how strong the container is.

The same article tells us the the temperature falls to only 100K at night, so at night the beer would freeze.

The colour of the beer and/or the bottle may change the rate at which it boils or freezes because a dark beer and/or bottle will absorb more sunlight. However the end result will be the same.

Comment: Yeah, but it says `>100 K to <400 K`, so 400K is extreme temperature. I think the only question is about B.P.

Comment: Yes, 400K is only 27K above the boiling point, and that temperature is at the equator so if the beer was nearer the poles the boiling would be even more questionable. However remember that daylight lasts 14 days on the Moon, so the beer will be in the sunshine for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

The pressure on the moon is essentially zero, and the liquid would (almost, unless you have some real exotic beer) certainly vaporize. Any (regular) container would explode due to the pressure applied by the liquid molecules inside, and the lack of pressure pushing the liquid together would cause the liquid to vaporize.

Even if it freezes, when that side of the moon sees the sun... temperatures skyrocket and liquid vaporizes.