# What happens when an astronaut opens cork of a bottle with water at 30°C on moons surface?

Tags: states-of-matter

The answer to this question is given as : water will start to boil and freez ultmately . How and why is it like this.??

Comment: Related to: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/45901/what-gonna-happen-to-beer-on-the-moon/45906#45906

Comment: Do you mean a [*quart*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quart) of water?

Comment: Find the pressure on the moon and state of h2o at that temperature and pressure

Answer (score 1):

The temperature on the moon in direct sunlight is 125 deg centigrade. Water at 30 degrees Celsius initially boils and emerges out of the bottle due to 1. Its temperature and 2. The low pressure on the moon. It freezes ultimately due to cooling since the atmosphere of the moon is thin, and so the temperature on the dark side is as low at minus 153 Celsius.